# pass JSON string to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, json

My server returns a valid JSON string ( JSONP ).

eg  `parseJSON ( {"NAME":"Tom"} );`

on client side i have this function implemented

```
function parseJSON ( myOBJ ) {

    //myOBJ is already a JSON object but I wanted to it to be a JSON string 
    // so that I can check
    // if browser supports JSON.parse otherwise do eval on that string.
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Answer (score 3):

> myOBJ is already a JSON object but I wanted to it to be a JSON
>   string  so that I can check if browser supports JSON.parse
>   otherwise do eval on that string.

If `myObj` is a JSON Object, the browser supports `JSON` (and `JSON.parse`), I would say. If you want to convert back to string, `JSON.stringify`. If you don't trust the browser, download [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). Don't use `eval`.

**[edit]**
In your case, seeing it's coming from a a ***JSONP*** request, the object such a request returns *is* a string, and that string is parsed into a script tag, after which it will be evaluated already. All browsers should support that, there's no client side JSON involved here I think.

Comment: THanks for your reply. THe problem is I don't know the behavior when JSON.parse is not supported by the browser. How do I write code within parseJSON function to handle this situation. Will myObj be a string still.

Comment: Hi kaushal kishore, if the browser doesn't support JSON natively, you'll need an external script to parse it (like json2.js). But see my edits to the answer also.